# Как связать механизм SIGNAL-SLOT с динамическим QcheckBox-oм

Tags: c++, qt

Как связать механизм SIGNAL-SLOT с динамическим QcheckBox-oм ??

В общем я добавил connect но почему не отработал код.

*---Вот код ---*

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QList>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void start_sending(bool); // принажатии на чекбокс то выполниться этот слот (отправка сообщений)


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;


    //    QList<QWidget*> myUiList;  

    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
    QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    // !!! почему-то не отрабатывает (ошибок не выводит)
    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету


    checkBox->setText(QString::number(666));
    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой
    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)

    // myUiList.append(checkBoxWidget);
}

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
    qDebug() << "start_sending  "  ;
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks: "<< " TRUE" ;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
    }
}
```

Comment: перенесите вызов connect туда, где чек бокс создается.  Например, в конец функции on_pushButton_clicked

Comment: `checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс` из cpp файла

Вы его здесь не объявляете и не инициализируете. Вы здесь создаёте новый и сохраняете указатель на новый чекбокс в поле класса `checkBox`. А объявляете и инициализируете вы его в заголовочном файле, вот там у вас правильный комментарий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнил совет @KoVadim - a  и все заработало.

Надо было перенести connect туда, где чек бокс создается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*--- Вот код ---*

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "QDebug"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "on_pushButton_clicked  "  ;

    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету

    connect(checkBox, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this, SLOT(start_sending(bool))); // соединение всех чекетов с "действием"  start_sending


    checkBox->setText(QString::number(666));
    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой
    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)

 }

void MainWindow::start_sending(bool Value)
{
    qDebug() << "start_sending  "  ;
    // когда нажата отрабатывает, отжата то не отрабатывает
    if (Value == true)
    {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks: "<< " TRUE" ;
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "chekbocks:" << " False";
    }
}
```